# Vbs getting value from excel matrix table to txt

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Currently I'm writing a VBS to get the value from a excel report table.
Tried to use DO until loop to get all matrix data.
However my script only can get the result by one loop only (only one line row X col)but can't get into next loop.
Can please to advise I missing any value to let the script working on next col?

Thanks very much.

```
    Set Args = WScript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

WScript.echo "cYear," & "cMonth," & "cEntity," & "cAccount,"& "cAmount" 

cFile = "C:\XXX.xlsx"


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(cFile)
Set objFile = fso.GetFile(cFile)
cFilename = fso.GetFileName(objFile)

        intRow = 21
        intCol = 8

        'Read xlsx data



            Do Until objExcel.Cells(13, intCol).Value = ""

                Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = ""
                cYear = objExcel.Cells(2, 2)
                cMonth = objExcel.Cells(3, 2)
                cEntity = objExcel.Cells (13, intCol)  
                cAccount = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2)            
                cAmount = objExcel.Cells(intRow, intCol)

                        WScript.echo  cYear &","&  cMonth&"," & cEntity&"," & cAccount&"," &  cAmount 

    exit do

        intRow= intRow + 1  

        Loop 

        intCol = intCol + 1

        loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dinesh iterated, Exit do is definitely the culprit causing your code to only produce 1 Row of data.

```
cFile = "C:\XXX.xlsx"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(cFile)
Set objFile = fso.GetFile(cFile)
cFilename = fso.GetFileName(objFile)
intRow = 21
intCol = 8
'Read xlsx data
Do Until objExcel.Cells(13, intCol).Value = ""
    Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = ""
        cYear = objExcel.Cells(2, 2)
        cMonth = objExcel.Cells(3, 2)
        cEntity = objExcel.Cells (13, intCol)
        cAccount = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2)
        cAmount = objExcel.Cells(intRow, intCol)
        WScript.echo  cYear &","&  cMonth&"," & cEntity&"," & cAccount&"," &  cAmount
        'Will cause the do to terminate after the first row value.
        'exit do
        intRow= intRow + 1
    Loop 
    intCol = intCol + 1
Loop
```

So I did a test of my own, this was the output. Used a tiny macro to fill a spreadsheet 100 rows x 20 columns.

```
Cell B Row 2,Cell B Row 3,Cell H Row 13,Cell B Row 21,Cell H Row 21
Cell B Row 2,Cell B Row 3,Cell H Row 13,Cell B Row 22,Cell H Row 22
Cell B Row 2,Cell B Row 3,Cell H Row 13,Cell B Row 23,Cell H Row 23
Cell B Row 2,Cell B Row 3,Cell H Row 13,Cell B Row 24,Cell H Row 24
```

Comment: Still the same , tried to remove "exit do" .But the script still only loop for one "row x col" only , can't loop the full table matrix

Comment: Can you provide a dummy sample of the spreadsheet in a CSV format? One other thought to consider is to add some W script Echoes and run it from command line to see exactly what data is processing and see if there's a repeat value over and over you might find a small error in your script but without seeing the sample
 data it's hard to tell you what's wrong

Comment: @KennethChiu I ran a simple test - see above. Does that help understand where the data is coming from?

Comment: I removed the 'exit do' then reset value to the 1st row then make it done

Answer (score 1):

**Try by removing 'exit do' line from your code**.
I guess it works. But do paste your excel sample for our better understanding the issue

Comment: Why are you iterating over both columns and rows?  If you data is 5 columns by 10 rows you'll get 50 records.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, thanks ,I removed the 'exit do' then reset value to the 1st row then make it done.